# Selenium WebDriver Clicking same element in FF and IE

Tags: selenium

Following works fine in IE, in FF it gives `ElementNotVisibleException`

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[4]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]")).click();
```

While following works in FF, in IE it doesn't do anything:

```
WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[4]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element1);
```

I'm using `IE 9.0` (with 32 bit IEDriverServe.exe) and `FF 23.0`.

Here is the Code:

```
<div id="popup_12" class="dijitPopup dijitMenuPopup" style="z-index: 1000; right: auto; left: 45px; top: 27px; visibility: visible; display: none;" role="presentation" dijitpopupparent="dijit_MenuBar_0">
 <table class="dijit dijitMenu dijitReset dijitMenuTable dijitMenuPassive" cellspacing="0" data-dojo-attach-event="onkeypress:_onKeyPress" tabindex="0" role="menu" widgetid="dijit_Menu_1" style="top: 0px; visibility: visible;">
  <tbody class="dijitReset" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode">
   <tr class="dijitReset dijitMenuItem" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem" data-dojo-attach-point="focusNode" aria-labelledby="dijit_PopupMenuItem_1_text dijit_PopupMenuItem_1_accel" style="-moz-user-select: none;" widgetid="dijit_PopupMenuItem_1" aria-haspopup="true">
       <td class="dijitReset dijitMenuItemIconCell" role="presentation">
       <td id="dijit_PopupMenuItem_1_text" class="dijitReset dijitMenuItemLabel" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode" colspan="2">XXXXX</td>






<div id="popup_23" class="dijitPopup dijitMenuPopup" style="z-index: 1001; right: auto; left: 117px; top: 0px; visibility: visible; display: none;" role="presentation" dijitpopupparent="dijit_Menu_1">
  <table class="dijit dijitMenu dijitReset dijitMenuTable dijitMenuPassive" cellspacing="0" data-dojo-attach-event="onkeypress:_onKeyPress" tabindex="0" role="menu" widgetid="dijit_Menu_2" style="top: 0px; visibility: visible;">
    <tbody class="dijitReset" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode">
        <tr class="dijitReset dijitMenuItem" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem" data-dojo-attach-point="focusNode" aria-labelledby="dijit_MenuItem_3_text dijit_MenuItem_3_accel" style="-moz-user-select: none;" widgetid="dijit_MenuItem_3">
        <tr class="dijitReset dijitMenuItem" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem" data-dojo-attach-point="focusNode" aria-labelledby="dijit_MenuItem_4_text dijit_MenuItem_4_accel" style="-moz-user-select: none;" widgetid="dijit_MenuItem_4">
        <tr class="dijitMenuSeparator" style="-moz-user-select: none;" widgetid="dijit_MenuSeparator_0">
        <tr class="dijitReset dijitMenuItem" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem" data-dojo-attach-point="focusNode" aria-labelledby="dijit_MenuItem_5_text dijit_MenuItem_5_accel" style="-moz-user-select: none;" widgetid="dijit_MenuItem_5">
                <td class="dijitReset dijitMenuItemIconCell" role="presentation">
                <td id="dijit_MenuItem_5_text" class="dijitReset dijitMenuItemLabel" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode" colspan="2">YYYYY</td>
```

I have to click Item XXXXX and Item YYYYY

div id with popup_12 and popup_23 changes every time the page is loaded or the item is clicked

Item YYYYY is displayed only when Item XXXXX is clicked

With FF using javascript executor and xpath or CSS selector it works perfectly, however with IE it doesn't

For this to work with IE I have to use xpath or CSS without javascript executor but again this time it doesn't works with FF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XXXXX and YYYYY

```
int no_of_popups = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div[id*='popup']")).size();

for(int i=1;i<=no_of_popups;i++)

{

String text = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.dijitPopup:nth-of-type("+i+
") > table.dijitReset > tbody.dijitReset > tr.dijitMenuItem > td.dijitMenuItemLabel")).getText();

  S.O.P(text);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always see if the element is displayed (visible, not just in the DOM)

```
el = driver.find_element(:xpath, 'xpath').displayed?
el.click
```

Answer (score 0):

We have tested thousands of websites and when doing so I have sometimes come across similar limitations within Selenium/WebDriver.  XPath is very powerful and we use it on a daily basis however assuming the page is using JQuery, you can do the entire search of the DOM using JQuery Selector and then you don't have to worry if the element is visible or not.

The code could look something like:
`driver.executeScript("$('td:contains(\"Foo\")').click();");`

I don't recommend walking the DOM the way you have, there are much more efficient was find what you are looking for.  However based on what you have above, you could do something like:
`driver.executeScript("$($($($('body').find('div')[4]).find('table:first').find('tbody:first').find('tr')[1]).find('td')[2]).click();");`

You can read more about jQuery Selectors on their [webpage](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Writing scripts for functional testing is easy with the Neustar Local Validator. You can see examples and watch videos on how to do this at: http://community.neustar.biz/community/wpm/getting_started/blog/2013/11/20/neustar-training-videos

Good Luck to you.
Brian Kranson
Neustar, Inc. / Professional Services Engineer

Comment: I have no experience in Selenium, but I found odd that you're promoting your product (because I can't say if it useful to the question). Know that it's has been discussed before : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limits-for-self-promotion-in-answers .

Comment: Marc, Thanks for highlighting the code, I should have done that originally.  Also thanks for adding the link to jQuery.  I understand your point on the promotion link, however local-validator makes it much easier to get up and running with Selenium to do functional testing.  Wish I knew about it years ago when I started doing this stuff.  And it is FREE.  I so understand your point, so I removed the link to our webpage and kept it strictly to the link on how to use local-validator, which I think will be useful to the poster.

Comment: No problem for the edit, it's normal things to do. With your edit, I don't see a problem with your answer if it could help the op, that's exactly what we want.

Comment: How does this take care of visible elements? This is also assuming there is jQuery on the page and therefore the tests will break if jQuery doesn't load. I can also see this can be easily done using CSS selectors. Therefore I don't see the benefit here?

Comment: This takes care of the visible, because javascript/jQuery does not care if the element is visible to click on it.  jQuery is used in the example because it is easy to locate elements within the DOM.  This is not a requirement, you can do the same with javascript.  Just takes more code.  You cannot do it with a CSS selector if the element is hidden. Perhaps there is span after the td that is visible, but the sample code is not here for us to review.

Comment: "You cannot do it with a CSS selector if the element is hidden" - completely and utterly false. The selector used has no bearing on whether or not an element is visible. It's *Selenium* that takes responsibility for deciding if an element is visible or not before attempting to click it. Again, this is using jQuery for the sake of using jQuery. Your answer may only work simply because it's JavaScript. Not because it's jQuery and most certainly not because of the selector used to find it (CSS selectors back jQuery selectors).

Comment: I will try with CSS Selector today and see what happens, I tried using jquery but got an error: "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: $ is not defined"

Comment: @user2788434, then you don't have jQuery on the page to use.

Comment: tried css selector still getting the same results as described in the first post

Comment: Tried Brian's JQuery Selector Approach, however with that the FF and IE are not interacting with the elements

Answer (score 0):

You can use WaitTime or wait for Element as below

```
int timeout=1;
while(timeout<=60)
{
    WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[4]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]"));

    if(element1.isDisplayed())
    {
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element1);
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            timeout++;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```